# Nginx allow specific file extensions for the root folder

Tags: nginx, config

I have a site running on php Modx Revo engine and served by nginx. I have a lot of files in the root folder and now they are accessible from the internet with *mysite.com/README.md* urls. I want to deny access to all of them except files with extensions I want to manually specify (json, js, html and png);
Here is my nginx config

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name mysite.com;
    access_log off;
    root /var/www/mysite.com;
    index index.php;

    #ssl stuff

    location / {
        root /var/www/mysite.com;
        if (!-e $request_filename) {
                rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
        }
        
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_ignore_client_abort on;
        fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME $http_host;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 128k;
    }

    location ~*^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|zip|pdf|js|ico|html) {
        root   /var/www/mysite.com/;
        access_log off;
        expires max;
    }
  
}
```

I need help with new nginx rule to deny access to all files in the root folder (site.com/cronjob.sh, site.com/anyfile.anyext) **except** files with *.json, .js, .html, .png* extensions (site.com/data.json, site.com/pic.png)

Comment: What about `.php`? I notice that your application uses the URI `/index.php`.

Comment: index.php should work fo sure